# The order of the scoped config files

Tags: magento2, configuration, scope, di, area

In Magento 2, you can have some config files be scoped.
For example `di.xml` can be present in the `etc` folder of a module and/or `etc/frontend` and/or `etc/adminhtml`.
Same goes for `events.xml` and maybe others.
I know that the one from `etc/frontend` does not get loaded in the admin area and `etc/adminhtml` is not loaded in the frontend.
But what is the order of loading them in an area?

- etc/di.xml
- etc/frontend/di.xml

or

- etc/frontend/di.xml
- etc/di.xml

Please support your answer with some code or at least a link to the code. 
Don't provide a simple "this way/that way" answer.

Comment: Last 2 lines of question is really awesome :-)

Comment: Are you ask for same method call in both files and loading order of files?

Comment: @Rakesh As far as I know, the files are merged into a big config and the same lines in both files are overwritten. I'm asking what overwrites what and where does that happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure the system merges the configuration with no explicit order.

In `Magento/Framework/App/Utility/Files` there's the following methods that gets all the `di.xml` from the module and merge them, according to the code the `etc/di.xml` is always first in the merge process:

```
public function getDiConfigs($asDataSet = false)
{
    $primaryConfigs = Glob::glob(BP . '/app/etc/{di.xml,*/di.xml}', Glob::GLOB_BRACE);
    $moduleConfigs = [];
    foreach ($this->componentRegistrar->getPaths(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE) as $moduleDir) {
        $moduleConfigs = array_merge(
            $moduleConfigs,
            Glob::glob($moduleDir . '/etc/{di,*/di}.xml', Glob::GLOB_BRACE)
        );
    }
    $configs = array_merge($primaryConfigs, $moduleConfigs);
    if ($asDataSet) {
        $output = [];
        foreach ($configs as $file) {
            $output[$file] = [$file];
        }
        return $output;
    }
    return $configs;
}
```

The system loads the config based on the area: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Area.php#L229

The `ConfigLoaderInterface` is the interface that implements the `load` method based on the area

Answer (score 4):

Whenever we have created two di.xml file for different area like,
one di.xml file in etc base folder and one di.xml file are call inside {area}/di.xml file.

> Final outcomes are come from base di.xml file not from area di.xml
>   file.

Below result are outcomes of override files,

This code for override topmenu block,

**app/code/Package/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Package_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Package/Module/etc/di.xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Package\Module\Block\Topmenu"/>
</config>
```

same **Topment.php** file override by area file like in frontend **di.xml** file,

```
app/code/Package/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml file,

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Package\Module\Block\Fronttop"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Package/Module/Topmenu.php**

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Block;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected $categoryFactory;

    protected $_filterProvider;

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,      
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory $treeFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        array $data = []    
    ){    
        echo 'final file call base area...';      
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;  
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        parent::__construct($context,$nodeFactory,$treeFactory,$data);    
    }

    public function test1(){
        //code goes here...
    }
}
```

**app/code/Package/Module/Fronttop.php**

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Block;

class Fronttop extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected $categoryFactory;

    protected $_filterProvider;

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,      
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory $treeFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        array $data = []    
    ){  
        echo 'final file call frontend area...';    
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;  
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        parent::__construct($context,$nodeFactory,$treeFactory,$data);    
    }

    public function test1(){
        //code goes here...
    }
}
```

After checking inside frontend,

you have to see at top, message are display from construct with **`final file call base area..`** from `etc/di.xml` file override method. in our case `Fronttop.php` file;

Here we have create two **di.xml** file with calling same **Topmenu.php** file and final result are comes from base **di.xml** file.

Override file using frontend di.xml in our case, `Package\Module\Block\Topmenu.php` file is not call at all.

Comment: good example, but I was looking for the core code that loads the `di.xml` files and maybe get an idea from there about how the order of the files is.